# Blank page without errors when using post in go code

Tags: html, mysql, go, post

I'm new to Go programming and I am writing a function to post into an alternate key as the primary key auto-increments using Go, Mysql, and template.HTML package.

After troubleshooting for the last few days I am loading a blank html page.

Any suggestions on best practice or ways I should troubleshoot in the future would be so appreciated.

Thank you so much for any help you are willing to offer!

I used linters and formatters to ensure that the code is correctly formatted, used print statements, and rebuilt the function and html content from scratch to narrow it down.

HTTP handler

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type watchInfo struct {
    ID    int
    Brand string
}

var (
    tpl *template.Template
    // cnn, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(db:3306)/appdb")
)

//function to connect to db
func dbConn() (db *sql.DB) {
    dbDriver := "mysql"
    dbUser := "root"
    dbPass := "root"
    dbName := "appdb"
    db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUser+":"+dbPass+"@tcp"+"(db:3306)/"+dbName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("dbConn not work")
    }
    return db
}

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("/go/templates/*"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", uploadWatchInfo)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

//This function get watch id and brand using getWatch function and passes them to the gohtml template file
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := dbConn()
    defer db.Close()
    scanWatches, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM watches order by id")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    watch := watchInfo{}
    watchSlice := []watchInfo{}

    for scanWatches.Next() {
        var id int
        var brand string
        err = scanWatches.Scan(&id, &brand)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("sW.Scan didn't work")
        }
        watch.ID = id
        watch.Brand = brand
        watchSlice = append(watchSlice, watch)

    }
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "pic.gohtml", watchSlice)

}

func uploadWatchInfo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := dbConn()
    defer db.Close()
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        brand := r.FormValue("brand")
        insForm, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO watches(brand) VALUES(?)")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error)
        }
        insForm.Exec(brand)
        err = tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "upload.gohtml", watchInfo{Brand: brand})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error)
        }
    }

}

//this is handling an error and can be called in other page functions
func HandleError(w http.ResponseWriter, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Index did not work. error in index")
    }
}
```

HTML Template

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>upload page</h1>

<form method="POST" action="insert">
      <label> brand </label><input type="text" name="brand"/><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Save brand"/>
    </form>

<a href="/">Index</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I Expect my handler to insert the string value into the database and print the confirmation in the terminal.

Comment: Do you have a request handler that also handles the GET request that displays the template you have? When you load the page, it will be a GET request for that URL, and for that you should execute your template and return the HTML page. When it is submitted, it will be the POST request, and the function you included here should run and insert the record to the db (or fail).

Comment: The expression `struct{Value: value}` is not valid Go.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: you said you have rebuilt from scratch to narrow the problem, can you share the whole minimal reproducible example you are compiling ?

Comment: I have updated my code for those of you who were saying I didn't have enough there. My index function/handler works with my html page as intended. Let me know if you need more info. Thank you so much!